# Vue - how to change value in data from async method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify to create a client side for a web app and I have some async methods that are getting data from a nodejs server. The problem I am having is that I cannot get the values in data to change to the data I am fetching. My data looks like this:

```
  data() {
  return {
    //holds data coming from server
      loading: false,
      cards: [
        {title: 'Eos Lab', os: 'Linux', roomno: 'idk', comps: "0"},
        {title: 'Arch Lab', os: 'Linux', roomno: 'idk', comps: "0"},
        {title: 'Data Comm Lab', os: 'Linux', roomno: 'idk', comps: "0"}
      ],
  }
},
```

and my async function looks like this, I have tried creating a variable self = this which I have read might fix it, but the error I get is "cannot read property "0" of undefined"

```
 methods: {
  async getEosComp() {
    var self = this
    this.loading = true
    collectDataService.getMakEosTotalComp()
    .then(data => {
      self.data[0].comps = data
      self.loading = false
    })
  },
```

Comment: What is `data[0].comps` ? There is no `data` property in an object returned by `data()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `this.cards` instead of `this.data` and use `this.$set` to update the data at the given index:

```
    .then(data => {
      this.$set(this.cards,0,{...this.cards[0],comps: data})
      this.loading = false
    })
```